# Write a Java program to repeat a String 100 times but add 8 unique typos at 8 random Strings

Tags: java

> A common punishment for school children is to write out a sentence multiple times. Write a Java stand-alone program that will write out the following sentence one hundred times: "I will never spam my friends again." Your program should number each of the sentences and it should make eight different randomlooking typos.

This is what i was able to do so far. Unable to get it going together.

```
public class Punishment {

    public static void textgen(int x) {
        System.out.println(x + ") I will never spam my friends again");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "I will ever spam my friends again.";
        String b = " will never spam my friends again.";
        String c = "I will neer spam my friends again.";
        String d = "I will never pam my friends again.";
        String e = "I will never spam my riends again.";
        String f = "I will never spam my friends gain.";
        String g = "I will never spam y friends again.";
        String h = "I will never sam my friends agn.";

        String typos[] = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h};
        int[] exitng = new int[8];

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=1; i<=100; i++){
            list.add(new Integer(i));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
            exitng[i] = list.get(i);
            System.out.println( list.get(i)+")- "+typos[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
             textgen(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an idea:

```
// initialize result without typos
String[] sentences = new String[100];
Arrays.fill(sentences, "I will never spam my friends again.");

// generate 8 unique typo indexes
Set<Integer> typoIndexes = new HashSet<>();
while (typoIndexes.size() < 8) {
    typoIndexes.add(Math.random() * 100);
}

// create a typo at each typo index
for(int index : typoIndexes) { 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sentences[index]);
    char char1 = char2 = char1;
    int pos1, pos2;
    while (char1 != char2) {
        pos1 = Math.random(sb.length());
        char1 = sb.charAt(pos1);
        pos2 = Math.random(sb.length());
        char2 = sb.charAt(pos2);
    }
    sb.setCharAt(pos1, char2);
    sb.setCharAt(pos2, char1);
    sentences[index] = sb.toString();
}
```

Note: uncompiled, untested

Comment: `A common punishment for school children is to write out a sentence multiple times. Write a Java stand-alone program that will write out the following sentence one hundred times: “I will never spam my friends again.” Your program should number each of the sentences and it should make eight different randomlooking typos` Is this your homework copy/paste ? Looks like it. `This is what i was able to do so far. Unable to get it going together.` ? What's wrong ? Whats the problem? Edit your post and ad a question to it.

Comment: it would be much cooler to insert random typos into the correct sentence than just prefabricate 8 sentences with typos

Comment: Do not ask your homework on stackoverflow.

Comment: @HarunErgül Homework questions are OK as long as they are clear and are not "give-me-teh-codes".

Comment: @Pshemo `This is what i was able to do so far. Unable to get it going together.` this looks like * give-me-teh-codes* to me me. No explanation at all.

Comment: I hate it when a question is closed/put on hold whilst I am working on an answer!

Comment: If he wants to score higher he can often improve the code, otherwise he might only score medium. And often the OP will learn from the code.

Comment: I think we got a hate team on assignment questions.

Comment: @Nightcrawler if you think that pasting the homework and code with 0 explanation (because *This is what i was able to do so far. Unable to get it going together.* is not an explanation, it's an excuse), not even a clear and precise question but just *fix-mah-code* attitude, is the way to go, I will just say I disagree. Asking for help is not wrong, no matter if it's for your job, or homework, but those downvotes are well deserved in my opinion. Still, I tried to help. Unfortunately, I misunderstood the task, and the proper answer was posted so I deleted mine. Don't be the defender of the poor.

Comment: @UDKOX I understand what you are saying. Live and let live :-)

Answer (score 2):

- add 8 sentences with typos to your array or list
- add rest of proper sentences
- shuffle entire array or list
- print elements

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

You should implement a function to produce 8 random sentences with typos instead of prefabricate them to score better with your teacher.

---

Hmm, this is kind of like @Pschemo, but here goes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "I will ever spam my friends again.";
    String b = " will never spam my friends again.";
    String c = "I will neer spam my friends again.";
    String d = "I will never pam my friends again.";
    String e = "I will never spam my riends again.";
    String f = "I will never spam my friends gain.";
    String g = "I will never spam y friends again.";
    String h = "I will never sam my friends agn.";

    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();

    // Add the right sentence 92 time.
    for (int i = 0; i < 92; i++) {
        l.add("I will never spam my friends again.");
    }

    // Add 8 different typo sentences.
    l.add(a);
    l.add(b);
    l.add(c);
    l.add(d);
    l.add(e);
    l.add(f);
    l.add(g);
    l.add(h);

    // Shuffle and print.
    Collections.shuffle(l);

    int i = 1;
    for (String s: l) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%d) %s", i++, s));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are awesome :)

Comment: Costed me a downvote because I solved your assignment :P

Comment: *upvoted because of unneeded downvote*

Comment: How would you implement a function to randomize the typos? What thought process would go into the creation of that function?